# Cannot open: Permission denied

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to install a library using a script I found (https://gist.github.com/kparrish/6440812) but when I run the script I get the following error message:

> tar (child): /root/Downloads/spglib-1.5.2.tar.gz: Cannot open: Permission denied

How can I fix this? Alternatively, can anyone recommend another way of installing spglib? I'm very new to ubuntu and I have no prior experience unfortunately.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure why you seem to have downloaded it as root...but avoid doing that.

Comment: To fix your problem you can follow [iceblizzard's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1255451/991676), but I strongly suggest you to learn a bit about permissions - they're important for Linux security and privacy and they are very useful in some situations. You can begin with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions.

Answer (score 1):

Just clone the git repo and build. You need to install `git`, `make` and `cmake` for this to work. If not installed, use the following to install:

```
sudo apt install git build-essential cmake
```

Then clone and build:

```
git clone https://github.com/spglib/spglib.git
cd spglib
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```